# Facebook PHP SDK Verifications after login

Tags: php, facebook

As a total stranger to facebook and its uses, I ask you the following question about login a user:

When using the latest php SDK (as of today, php-sdk-3.2.3), I read the SDK documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and can login a user and get information from them according to the permissions requested.

Still, there's this other document, about manually building a login flow:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

There's a few points there about "Confirming identity" and exchanging tokens I thought were worth toying with. When I try to combine the SDK methods with these other aspects, the second one to execute always fails (something about "this authorization code has been used", that I can understand as a part of the Oauth specs). I am going crazy exchanging and renewing tokens but maybe that's not neccesary...

... Here's the question: does the php SDK part do these kind of confirmations for you?. Is it secure enough?. In that case, this - almost too familiar, quick and dirty - code is just what I need to get the user info, right?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array( [something something]));
if($facebook->getUser()) 
{
    try 
    {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    } 
    catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
    {   
        echo '<a href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'">login.</a>';
    }   
} 
else
{
    echo '<a href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'">login.</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the SDK does all this for you - the manually building a login flow documentation is intended for people who are not using an SDK (for example where no SDK exists for the language they are using).

I checked the [PHP SDK source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php), just to be sure - **getUser()** calls **getUserFromAvailableData()** which, if you're not an app inside Facebook (with a signed request) it calls **getAccessToken()** which calls **getUserAccessToken()** which in turn calls **getAccessTokenFromCode()** which does the exchange of a code for an accessToken. If it has a signed request (is an app on Facebook) then the access token is provided in the POST data and a code does not need to be exchanged. Phew!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also checked, hacked and slashed the SDK in getUrl, makeRequest and its friends, but did not see the requests I was expecting... Anyhow, as a foreigner to all things facebook, I accept your answer and your time, incoming upvote :). Thanks again.